# Trying to install tensorflow 1.12.0 in an Anaconda 3 virtual python environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Trying to install tensorflow on a virtual environment (`Anaconda 3` and `Python 3.6`) on a Windows 10 computer.

After installing Anaconda, I go to the Anaconda prompt and key in the Following:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_cpu pip python=3.6
activate tensorflow_cpu
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

After that, I enter these in `python` shell:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following error message:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: may be helpful, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386

Comment: and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17393

Comment: try to install tensorflow on python 3.5 instead of python 3.6. I also faced this problem while installing tensorflow on python 3.6 in anaconda.

Comment: Thanks guys, I came across a post saying that there is a problem with installations on Windows (10 & otherwise) if you install the latest version so I did the following: pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.5 and it works just fine. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

```
conda create -n tensorflow==1.12.0
conda activate tensorflow==1.12.0
```

Try theses lines in anaconda prompt